# Java Multithread and Nodejs Cluster

Tags: java, node.js

We can use nodejs cluster to run multiple processes...

While the equivalent in java is multi-thread...

I have a http listener running on nodejs (without clustering), and I'm using Java to call this nodejs http (using java.lang.Thread class)

If I have concurrently 300 request, will it create multiple instances of nodejs? Will nodejs be a bottle neck?

Comment: Depends how your servers are designed. if there is only one instance of NodeJS then all 300 concurrent requests from Java will be directed to only one instance of NodeJS

Comment: I have only one instace of nodejs server with one listener. So means all calls from Java (concurrently) will be queued and process one by one in nodejs?

Answer (score 3):

NodeJS is single-threaded. It means that whatever number of http calls you make, it will queue them and process them. You'll have a longer response time thought if you overload Node JS with hundreds on call in a few seconds.

See [this guide](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) about the event loop for further informations

**Edit** : I did not see the cluster part. It'll allow you to use multiple instances, hence using more cores in your processor and processing more actions at the same time. I would say that the best thing to do is to benchmark a lot of operations to see if it's enough to process hundreds of call in a few seconds

Comment: Hi @S. Miranda. Thanks for replying. Do you have any suggestion on processing this faster on nodejs? Since java side is already running multiple thread, the nodejs portion is the bottleneck here

Comment: Have you been able to try a lot of http calls on your node JS side in cluster mode ? I think you'll not necessarly see yourself in a bottleneck, if you configure the number of node JS instances to be the same as the number of Java instances you won't have any problem, but it's subject to test.

Comment: About to try it out. In the mean time, would like to accept more advise :D

Comment: I found [this blog post](https://blog.jayway.com/2015/04/13/600k-concurrent-websocket-connections-on-aws-using-node-js/). It's from 2015, but I think you can be confident about handling some hundreds of HTTP requests :)

It's not entirely related to what you do but demonstrate the power of the Chrome V8 engine

Comment: "It means that whatever number of http calls you make, it will queue them and process them." Only if that request processing is 100% CPU-bound or otherwise blocking. If you make a database call (or other async workload) in there, that single thread can be multiplexed to work on many requests.

Answer (score 2):

Even though NodeJS is single-threaded, asynchronous operations are run in separate threads thanks to its [Event Loop](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) architecture.

> If I have concurrently 300 request, will it create multiple instances of nodejs?

No, unless you are running a node cluster, only a single Node proccess (and thread) will handle the requests.

> Will nodejs be a bottle neck?

If most of your work is asynchronous, then it will be able to perform those tasks in parallel and shouldn't be a bottleneck. Also, you can scale the application by creating a node process for each available core in the CPU and/or by deploying the process in multiple computer instances.

However, it's important to note the distinctions between a Java multithread application and a Node cluster application (or multiproccess).

- processes are typically independent, while threads exist as subsets of a process
- processes carry considerably more state information than threads, whereas multiple
  threads within a process share process state as well as memory and other resources
- processes have separate address spaces, whereas threads share their address space
- processes interact only through system-provided inter-process communication mechanisms
  context switching between threads in the same process is typically faster than context switching between processes.

Therefore, if memory is scarce in your context, and if your instance has a multi-core processor, then NodeJS might indeed become a bottleneck.